# Deserializing to DynamicObject Using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net

If I want to deserialize to an `ExpandoObject` using Json.NET, I can do the following:

```
var obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(serializedData, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

But because I need to get back an object with a certain interface out of deserialization, I need to use a `DynamicObject` instead of `ExpandoObject`:

```
   public interface ISomeInterface
    {
        public string InterfaceMember { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClass: ISomeInterface
    {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public string InterfaceMember { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeClass2 : DynamicObject, ISomeInterface
    {
        public string InterfaceMember { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I do the following, I get an error:

```
       var obj = new SomeClass
        {
            InterfaceMember = "xyz",
            X = 3
        };

        string serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

        SomeClass2 obj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SomeClass2>(serializedData, new ExpandoObjectConverter());
```

And the error is:

> 'SomeClass2' does not contain a definition for 'X'

How can I make it work for a `DynamicObject`?

NOTE: I am providing the concrete class `SomeClass` here just for the sake of the example. At runtime, it can actually be any type implementing `ISomeInterface`. So, I cannot deserialize directly to `SomeClass`. My actual goal is to deserialize to `ISomeInterface`.

Comment: Serializing to an arbitrary type implementing a certain interface still doesn't mandate using `DynamicObject`. You can just use the overload that takes a `Type` at runtime (providing the actual type, and casting to `ISomeInterface` afterwards).

Comment: It's because TryGetMember for X return false ... if you would override it (both TryGet/TrySet) then this would work

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0ml3L0 also SomeClass2  has no definition of X at compile time ... so obviosuly for variable of type `SomeClass2` is not valid to ask about property X ... but for `dynamic` it is valid

Comment: @Selvin I tried your solution and it works for creating this dynamic object. But when I serialize it again, it creates an empty object: Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(t));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code for `SomeClass2` solves the problem (thanks to @Selvin's comment and sample fiddle):

```
public class SomeClass2 : DynamicObject, ISomeInterface
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    [JsonProperty]
    public string InterfaceMember { get; set; }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        return dictionary.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        dictionary[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return dictionary.Keys;
    }
}
```

I just added the `GetDynamicMemberNames`override and added `[JsonProperty]` attribute to the `InterfaceMember` property so that reserializing the deserialized dynamic object will not be empty.